# Setting aws-amplify user session manually

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have one cognito user pool that is used by multiple applications. I have a central auth application where users can login/signup/resetPasswords/etc anything auth related.

I have five other application that users can access. Rather than having them log into each application I embed the auth application into an iframe. If the user is logged in it does a postMessage to the parent document, or if the token is not valid once the user logs in, it will do a postMessage with the cognito session object.

Is there something such as Auth.setUserSession(session) that can be done in the parent document?
Right now I am having to build a bunch of strings with token and username values and saving them manually to localStorage.

I've been looking through the aws-amplify auth code, but I don't see anything that can accomplish this.

Thanks.

In the parent document:

```
    const eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? 'addEventListener' : 'attachEvent';
        const eventListener = window[eventMethod];
        const messageEvent = eventMethod === 'attachEvent' ? 'onmessage' : 'message';
        eventListener(messageEvent, async evt => {
          const session = _.get(evt, 'data.session');
          if (session) {
              this.saveUserSession(session);
          }
        }, false);

        private saveUserSession(session) {
// this is the code that I would like to simplify with something
// Auth.setUserSession(session)

            const cognitoClientId = environment.COGNITO.Auth.userPoolWebClientId;

            const userName = _.get(session, 'idToken.payload.email', '');
            const makeKey = (name) => `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.${cognitoClientId}.${userName}.${name}`;

            localStorage.setItem(makeKey('accessToken'), JSON.stringify(_.get(session, 'accessToken', '')));
            localStorage.setItem(makeKey('idToken'), JSON.stringify(_.get(session, 'idToken', '')));
            localStorage.setItem(makeKey('refreshToken'), JSON.stringify(_.get(session, 'refreshToken', '')));
            localStorage.setItem(makeKey('clockDrift'), JSON.stringify(_.get(session, 'clockDrift', '')));
            localStorage.setItem(`CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.${cognitoClientId}.LastAuthUser`, userName);
          }

In the auth application, after a user successfully logs in:

    const session = await Auth.currentSession();
          window.parent.postMessage({session}, '*');
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [amazon-cognito-identity-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js) to set up user session by providing cognito user session to `setSignInUserSession` method

```
const userPool = new CognitoUserPool({
  UserPoolId: `USER_POOL_ID`,
  ClientId: `APP_CLIENT_ID`,
});
const cognitoIdToken = new CognitoIdToken({
  IdToken: idToken,
});
const cognitoAccessToken = new CognitoAccessToken({
  AccessToken: accessToken,
});
const cognitoRefreshToken = new CognitoRefreshToken({
  RefreshToken: refreshToken,
});
const username = cognitoIdToken.payload.Username; // or what you use as username, e.g. email
const user = new CognitoUser({
  Username: username,
  Pool: userPool,
});
user.setSignInUserSession(new CognitoUserSession({
  AccessToken: cognitoAccessToken,
  IdToken: cognitoIdToken,
  RefreshToken: cognitoRefreshToken,
}));
```

Comment: Then what? How do you assign the CognitoUser to amplify internals currentSession so any API (like DataStore) would use this authentication ?

Comment: The above solution works perfectly for setting auth session, I'm using a custom auth flow (ionic auth connect) and with this setup my GraphQL api calls are now authenticated and auth token is automatically added to request header.