# Set session in Amplify Auth Android using AccessToken and RefreshToken

Tags: authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify-sdk-android

We do a custom authentication against Cognito and we get the AccessToken and RefreshToken in the client.

How can we pass these tokens to Amplify Auth Android SDK to set the session there?

Similar to this question, but for Android: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67872625/18770645